# How can I change keys in a dictionary to upper case and add values of the same key in the resulting dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {'A':110, 'a':100, 'T':50, 't':5}
```

I want to change the keys to upper case and combine `A+a` and `T+t` and add their values, so that the resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
d = {'A': 210, T: 55}
```

This is what I tried:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    k.upper(), v
```

and the result is:

```
('A', 110)
('A', 100)
('T', 50)
('t', 5)
```

I looks like tuples but I want to change it in the dictionary, so I tried to write a function:

```
def Upper(d):
    for k, v in d.items:
        k.upper(), v
    return d
```

but it returns the dictionary unchanged.

After I have changed the keys to upper case I had found this solution to how to add values of keys in a dictionary:

```
dict([(x, a[x] + b[x]) if (x in a and x in b) else (x, a[x]) if (x in a) else (x, b[x])
```

but first I need to get the keys to upper case!

Comment: With Python, you should be much more careful about indentation. Both your "what I've tried" examples had indentation errors that would have prevented the code from running at all.

Answer (score 14):

`Counter` does this quite nicely

```
>>> d = {'A':110, 'a':100, 'T':50, 't':5}
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     c.update({k.upper(): v})
... 
>>> c
Counter({'A': 210, 'T': 55})
```

Comment: @edg, you'll need at least Python2.7 for `Counter`

Answer (score 6):

`upper()` method doesn't change anything. You can use the following code:

```
def capitalize_keys(d):
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        upper_key = key.upper()
        result[upper_key] = result.get(upper_key, 0) + value
    return result
```

Comment: This works nicely, but why isn´t the new dictionary stored in d?

Comment: @edg: It's possible to write a code that changes (http://pastebin.com/FHgv9Y5p), but this implementation is less transparent and does approximately the same number of operations. Using above functions you could write `d = capitalize_keys(d)`.

Answer (score 2):

`defaultdict` is helpful:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = {'A':110, 'a':100, 'T':50, 't':5}
>>> new_d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for key, val in d.iteritems():
...     new_d[key.upper()] += val
...
>>> dict(new_d)
{'A': 210, 'T': 55}
```

Comment: When I try to do use the defaultdict ('new_d = defaultdict(0)'), I get this error message:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: This is because it should be `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: @edg fixed, use `int` instead of `0` while initializing `defaultdict` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to rebuild your dictionary. Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d={'A':110, 'a':100, 'T':50, 't':5}

def upper(d):
        nd=defaultdict(int)
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
                nd[k.upper()]+=v
        return dict(nd)

print d
print upper(d)
```

Output:

```
{'A': 110, 'a': 100, 'T': 50, 't': 5}
{'A': 210, 'T': 55}
```

Or use the solution from @citxx with `result.get(upper_key, 0) + value` and avoid the defaultdict altogether.

Comment: thanks, it returns the new dictionary like this after using the function: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 110, 'T': 50})
and when I look what´s in d (the original dictionary), I still get the old one... how do I return/store the new dictionary in d?

Comment: Just overwrite `d` with `d=upper(d)` and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

With this function (corrected):

```
>>> def upper_kdict(d):
...     r = {}
...     for k, v in d.items():
...             K = k.upper()
...             r[K] = v if not r.__contains__(K) else v + r[K]
...     return r
... 
>>> 
>>> d = {'a': 100, 'A': 110, 'b': 20, 'B': 1000, 'C': 150, 'c': 100, 'd': 180}
>>> upper_kdict(d)
{'A': 210, 'C': 250, 'B': 1020, 'D': 180}
```

Comment: "and combine A+a and T+t and add their values"; this means that `upper_dict(dict(a=1, A=1))` should return `{'A': 2}`; your function returns `{'A': 1}`.

Comment: *i.e.* please fix this limitation or delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'A':110, 'a':100, 'T':50, 't':5}
{i.lower(): d.get(i.lower(),0)+d.get(i.upper(),0) for i in d.keys()}
// {'a': 210, 't': 55}
```

If you want the keys in upper case then use

```
{i.upper(): d.get(i.lower(),0)+d.get(i.upper(),0) for i in d.keys()}
// {'A': 210, 'T': 55}
```

Output:

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a very long dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'A':110, 'a':100, 'T':50, 't':5}
d = dict((k, v + d.get(k.lower(), 0)) if (k == k.upper()) 
    else (k.upper(), v) for (k, v) in d.items() 
    if ((k == k.upper()) or (k == k.lower() and not (k.upper() in d))))
print d
```

Output:

```
{'A': 210, 'T': 55}
```